# Defining a vector with fixed size inside a class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

Following is the part of my code in C++

```
class Myclass 
{
    public:
       vector< vector<int> >edg(51); // <--- This line gives error
       // My methods go here
};
```

The line marked in the comments gives me the errors :
 `expected identifier before numeric constant` 
 `expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant`

But when I do the following it compiles without errors

```
  vector< vector<int> >edg(51); // Declaring globally worked fine
  class Myclass 
  {
    public:
       // My methods go here
  };
```

I figured it out that even if I just define `vector < vector<int> >edg` in first method it works fine, so the problem is with the constant size `51`, which I don't seem to understand. I tried googling but as my oop's concept are weak I did not understand much, could anyone explain why does this happen ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a limitation wrt. defining class members. If you want a fixed-size vector, just use `std::array` instead, which will allow you to do exactly that.

```
class Myclass 
{
    public:
       array< vector<int>, 51 >edg; 
};
```

Alternatively, you can declare the size in the constructor:

```
class Myclass 
{
    public:
       vector< vector<int> >edg; 
       Myclass() : edg(51) {}
};
```

Answer (score 7):

In-class initialisation can only be done with `=` or a brace-list, not with `()`. Since `vector` behaves differently with a brace-list, you'll need to use `=`.

```
vector< vector<int> > edg = vector< vector<int> >(51);
```

or initialise it in the constructor(s) in the old-fashioned manner.

```
MyClass() : edg(51) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having the problem of initialising a fixed size vector inside a class in C++ , you can do this.

```
class DSU{
 vector<int> rank;
 public:
 DSU(int n){
 rank.resize(n);
 }
```